# Accessing Azure AD API with certificate

Tags: java, azure, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to develop a stand alone java process which will look into a dedicated email inbox hosted by Azure Active Directory. The purpose is to retrieve a specific set of emails and perform operation. Azure AD is providing REST API to perform the same using Auth2.0 authorization. However, access token expires in 60 mins. or so. I want to use private/public key certification to perform the same. Is it achievable? If so, how to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a code sample for C# which seems to be similar with your needs, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential/. I think you can try to refer to the sample above to perform the needs in Java.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: the link  is broken